# JPA - Using null values in @DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, jpa

I was wondering if I could use the DiscriminatorValue to set apart two subtypes in the following manner:
B extends A

@DiscriminatorValue(**null**)
A

@DiscriminatorValue("Some-Value")
B extends A

The point is that I want to check if there is a **null** value in some DiscriminatorType.Char column.
I tried writing "" (empty string) as the value and also null. Niether worked.

Comment: is it just test? It is used by `EntityManager`. Do u need to check null value `DiscriminatorValue` in your query?

Answer (score 0):

The DiscriminatorValue is normally set by the implementation, and you should only need to set it when the implementation cannot properly tell two classes apart, like having duplicate class names or very long class names.

For example, in Hibernate/Postgres, the default discriminator is the simple class name. The only time I have ever had to set it is in deeply nested classes that run on longer than the name limit in the database.

So, long story short, don't specify a discriminator value unless you *must*.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation do not allow a null indicator, nor does the spec directly support it.

If you are using EclipseLink, you should be able to use a DescriptorCustomizer to add a null classIndicator mapping to the A's ClassDescriptor's inhertiancePolicy.